# How do I recover the launcher?

Tags: 11.04, launcher

My 7 yr old son recently attempted to get on the computer and rebooted it somehow. Now the launcher is missing and I am unable to use the system.

I have rebooted several times with the same results, but don't see anything other than the wallpaper.

Comment: What Ubuntu Launcher? what do you see when your PC boots up?.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu do you use?

Comment: Running Ubuntu 11.04 Desktop version the desktop shows the image I set up for it (a picture of my son).

Comment: Then you don't see the panel at the top or anything other than that wallpaper?

Comment: correct, I have rebooted several times with the same results.

Answer (score 1):

When you log in, you can choose which session to use. Make sure it's set to Ubuntu and not something else.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `unity --reset` in a terminal window. To open the terminal, try the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> key combination.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this did not work.

Comment: What exactly didn't work? Would it be too much to ask for the output of the 'unity --reset' command? You can use pastebin.com to post the output and then just provide the link.

Comment: It says command not found